# Is it possible to make an 'if this or that' statement without using a switch in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to make an `if` statement with an `or` in it. I know you get something like a `switch`. But if you don't want a `switch`, how would you do it?

So I want it to look something like the following (which doesn't work):

```
var number:Int = 1

if number == 1 or 5 {
    println("Lucy's Number")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the logical operator **||**    for "or".

```
if (number == 1 || number == 5)
    {
         //do something
    }
```

Documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of possible cases to check, you can group the values in an array and filter it:

```
if [1, 5, 9, 17, 33].filter({$0 == number}).count > 0 {
    println("Lucy's Number")
}
```

or even:

```
if filter([1, 5, 9, 17, 33], {$0 == number}).count > 0 {
    println("Lucy's Number")
}
```

Last, as suggested by @MartinR (often overlooked solutions are the simplest ones :)):

```
if contains([1, 5, 9, 17, 33], number) {
    println("Lucy's Number")
}
```

Comment: Perhaps slightly simpler: `if contains([1, 5, 9, 17, 33], number) ...`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dejan Skledars answer.. You don`t need brackets:

```
var number = 1
if number == 1 || number == 5 {
    println("yes")
}
```

And even better from Swift 1.2 you can use additional conditions using the keyword "where".